# The content loaded by ajax does not take the styles of the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

With ajax I am bringing content to upload my website with information. What the page does is load everything normally first, then execute the corresponding ajax, but when loading the ajax and placing the appropriate information, this information does not apply the styles of the web page. Here is an example of how my code would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Styles that you do not recognize -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" class="div-short"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:8000/api/pag/5",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                // Dynamic information
                $('#id').html(data);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone has some kind of solution or how it can be done, it is very useful for me. Thank you

Comment: You have to generate HTML somewhere. The contentType you're importing implies that JSON is coming in. Your success function should take the JSON data and create HTML that corresponds to the styles found in your style.css.

Comment: How to create an html, what do you mean? And this problem also I have it with jquery libraries, such as image galleries, zoom on images...

Comment: It really depends upon the actual format of the data being returned. If it's JSON, you need to learn about parsing JSON and converting it to HTML. See @JeffCasino 's answer below for an example of generating HTML. The parsing would happen before any appending.

Comment: try `$('#id').html(JSON.parse(data))` and see if it helps. You should see what is coming, you can alert it, at least you will get the form of the data. Is it being rendered and just not styled?

Comment: technically... it is in fact taking on the styles of the page. it's just the page has no styles that affect it in the way you seem to expect.

Comment: Basically, what happens is that the data json that I receive and that I put in html, are not being put in html?

Comment: What is this returning http://localhost:8000/api/pag/5 ? HTML or Json?

I see you are expecting JSON as a response? If so? how do you want style json?

Comment: I understood, what I bring is json, therefore it will not take any style? Do you have a way to fix it?

Comment: It depends on how  you want it to be rendered. Then you have to do some javascript to convert the jason in that form and apply css like this `.css({ set the properties here });` then you can push it to the DOM

Comment: This is a system that calls an api, this api returns certain data to fill the page. This data can be just text, or image, or an html element. What is not happening is that they take the styles of the page, now is it better understood?

Comment: The code is doing precisely what it was instructed. You directly appended the result of the ajax request, which is a json string, into the html of the page. it's going to be displayed as is. If you want to instead do more with it, like pull data from it and intermingle that data with html, you'll need more code to do that. It doesn't know what you wanted to do with it (and neither do we.)

Comment: What I want is for the styles to be applied to the data that I am putting on the page. Can not reload styles or render them?

Comment: @KevinB said it perfectly. I just put up an answer that **probably** resembles the result you're currently getting, as well as the **correct** way to parse JSON responses. It's not 100% clear what format you're desiring, but the snippet should convey the principle. If you're unable to draw from the principle to solve your problem, we will need more specifics and code from you to better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example Snippet**

In the example below...

- assume that `const data` is being returned from your ajax call
- ignore everything except the jQuery, since it's all just to show that styles come through-- the point is to focus on how the HTML is generated
- I'm aware I didn't use your exact code and IDs to create this snippet. That doesn't matter-- what matters is the educational takeaway you can get from seeing the data flowing.

```js
const data = '[{"species": "dog", "breed": "Husky", "name": "Kenna"},{"species": "cat", "breed": "Siamese", "name": "Jeff"},{"species": "dog", "breed": "Doberman", "name": "Bella"}]';

let parsed_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var html = "";

$.each(parsed_data, function(key, value) {
  html += '<div class="card"><h3>' + value.name + '</h3><p>Species: ' + value.species + '</p><p>Breed: ' + value.breed + '</p></div>';
});

$("#container").html(html);
```

```css
.card {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  cursor: default;
}

.card > h3 {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card > h3:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.card > p {
  color: #555;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Explanation**

Notice how the first thing I did with the data was run `jQuery.parseJSON()` on it. This takes the result from a string representation to a javascript object.

I then loop through the javascript object with `$.each`. I access the variables with the `funcParam.keyName` format (e.g. the first access `value.name`).

I finally included the generated HTML in a variable, and then used `.html()` to add it to my container after the `$.each` (which is faster than using `.append()` on each iteration of the loop).

**See below where the HTML generation code would be placed:**

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "http://localhost:8000/api/pag/5",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
      // run your HTML generation code (like my Snippet example) HERE
   }
});
```

Comment: Look at the images of this site:
http://cb-proyectos.com.ar/ZonaNorte/

There I am modifying the img tags, the src attribute to bring another image, but do not take the styles

Comment: @ThomasMarck I have *no clue* what your JSON looks like, but it sounds like what you're needing to do is parse the JSON and run a loop (just like I demoed above), but instead of plugging the data into html, the loop does something like ``$(".selected-image").attr("src", funcParam.keyName).attr("alt", "Some relevant text.");`` to update the source and alternate text of already-existent elements. Please note that unless you're also getting relevant IDs from the JSON, you'll need to use some other identifier (such as a class) to select multiple elements since they can't share an ID.

Comment: What I do is $ ('# img').attr('src', new_image);

Comment: I'm not confident that the variable ``new_image`` is doing anything without seeing how you're creating that variable. And again, consider that ``#img`` should only select **one** element in the DOM. Put some real effort into understanding JSON and how to grab data from it. There's a great *general* example in my answer, but it can only take you so far before you learn and apply the principles being demonstrated to you.

Comment: There's also the possibility that jQuery is not finding your elements if they were previously dynamically generated. In that case, you'll need to scope your selection to an element that's always been there (the common choice is "document"). You'd do this: ``$(document).find(".selected-image").attr("src", funcParam.keyName).attr("alt", "Some relevant text.");``

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with changes in DOM (via AJAX), you need to understand, that addClass() or something like toggleClass() will work only for currently present objects. All newly appended or loaded items will not be styled, unless they are chіldren of parents which have CSS for children. Loading external CSS sometimes is a hassle.

Good practice in my case came **to use variables in CSS**.
Examples of usage: you need to change skin of website/webapp, make a nightmode/daymode or just to style loaded elements correctly.

As example, let's take initial color of text and background in variables:

```
/* CSS for day mode */
:root {
  --textcolor: #333;
  --bgcolor: #fff;
}
```

JS allows you to change the variables in CSS (along with saving that information), here is handy [JS snippet](https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript#comment-512794) from Ciaran O'Kelly for manipulating with CSS variables:

```
/** 
 * Gets and sets css vars
 * get a css var:
 * cv('bgcolor') // Returns #ccc
 * set a css var:
 * cv('bgcolor','#f00') // Sets and returns #f00
*/
function cv(n,v) {
    if(n[0]!='-') n = '--'+n //allow passing with or without --
    if(v) document.documentElement.style.setProperty(n,v)
    return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(n);
}
```

And finally, user function to change UI. Styles will be aplicable to all present and yet not loaded elements in DOM:

```
function change_skin() {
    if($("#sk").text() == 'Night') {
        
        // Night mode skin
        cv('bgcolor','#666')
        cv('textcolor','#eee')
        
        // Change label
        $("#sk").text('Day')
        
    } else {

        // Day mode
        cv('bgcolor','#fff')
        cv('textcolor','#333')

        // Change label
        $("#sk").text('Night')

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to format your data in html... example

```
$('#id').append("<span class='yourclass'>"+ data.name +"</span>");
```

that way you make thediv with all the data and styles you need and then append it to your div #id

Comment: What happens is that I only bring text, I mean that the html element already has styles, and all I do is change the content of that element, but what I put does not take the corresponding styles, for example, an image would not respect the wide or high. If there is something that is not understood, let me know.

Comment: well first, the div '#id' does not exist, if you want to add the data in the `<div id="content" class="div-short">` then it has to be `$('#content').append(data);` now, you can check in chrome when data is include to your div and see what html is being generated.. so you can check clases etc.. plus you should add to your question a console.log of data, so we can see if its a json, html, etc and help you better

Comment: In my actual use, the code is attached, but I still do not take the corresponding styles, for example, the images do not have the width that I put in the styles. Also the data that I bring is in json, but I can use them without problems

Answer (score -2):

after get response add simple html with class for example

```
$('#id').append('<p class="test">test</p>');
```

and in the head add the following line

```
<style>
.test { font-size: 50px; }
</style>
```

if  your "p" get the given style that's means your problem with "data" variable